# PHP - Insert tags (<div>) between an other tags (<p>) in a string

Tags: php, string, dom, tags

I have a string in php that I get from a request (in fact, it's a string from CKEDITOR a WYSIWYG text editor) and I'm trying to insert tags (`div`) in other tags (`p`) and also get data attributes from the the `p` > `div` before.

It will be better to understand with this example:

```
$String =
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
        <span>Blabla1 </span><span>Blabla2</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    Blabla3 Blabla4
</p>
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="6" data-end="10">
        <span>Blabla10 </span><span>Blabla20</span>
    </div>
</p>
```

Here, the first and last `<p>` are OK ! but what I would like to to is for the 2nd `<p>`.

I need to put "`Blabla3 Blabla4`" in a `<div class="ST">` with the `data-start` and `data-end` attributes from the previous `<div>` (here `data-start = 0` and `data-end = 5` and get finally this :

```
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
        <span>Blabla1 </span><span>Blabla2</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
       Blabla3 Blabla4
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="6" data-end="10">
        <span>Blabla10 </span><span>Blabla20</span>
    </div>
</p>
```

The string can be also like this (with the `<p>` at the begining) In this case, put `data-start` and `data-end` to `0` :

```
<p>
    Blabla3 Blabla4
</p>
<p>
    <div data-start="0" data-end="5">
        <span>Blabla1 </span><span>Blabla2</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div data-start="6" data-end="10">
        <span>Blabla10 </span><span>Blabla20</span>
    </div>
</p>
```

Or like this (with 2 or more `<p>`) In this case put for both `data-start` and `data-end` to `1` and `5` like the previous:

```
<p>
    <div data-start="1" data-end="5">
        <span>Blabla1 </span><span>Blabla2</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    Blabla3 Blabla4
</p>
<p>
    Blabla5 Blabla6
</p>
<p>
    <div data-start="6" data-end="10">
        <span>Blabla10 </span><span>Blabla20</span>
    </div>
</p>
```

I have no idea how to manipulate the string... May be using regex ?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT 1**

I tried that:

`$value` =

```
string 
'<p><show class="st" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-moy="0.12125" data-time-start="0.28" id="1"><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="0.28">TEST1&nbsp; </word><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="1.25"> </word></show><show class="st" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-moy="0.13857142857143" data-time-start="0.28" id="11"><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="0.28">TEST2. </word><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="1.25"> </word></show><show class="st" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-moy="0.194" data-time-start="0.28" id="12"><word class="word" data-time-end="1.444" data-time-start="0.28">TEST3 </word></show></p>

    <p>TESTTTT</p>' (length=709)
```

My code (I'm using symfony2 and a Transformer) :

```
public function reverseTransform($value)
{
        $value_purified = strip_tags($value, '<p><show><strong><span><word><em><u>'); // Allow just tags bellow

        // Create a DOM with $value
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // autorise les balises non conforme html5
        $dom->loadHTML($value_purified); // Charge le string $value dans le DOM $dom
        libxml_use_internal_errors(false); // refuse les balises non conforme html5

        var_dump($dom);

        $pTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
        var_dump($pTags); 

        foreach ($pTags as $pTag) {
            var_dump($pTag);
            $valuePTagFull = $this->DOMinnerHTML($pTag);
            if (strpos($valuePTagFull,'<show') === false) {
                $valuePTagFull = "<show class='st'>".$valuePTagFull."</show>";
            } 
            var_dump($valuePTagFull);
        }

        $value_purified = strip_tags($value, '<show><strong><span><word><em><u>'); // Allow tags bellow (delete the <p> tag)
        var_dump($value_purified);
}

private function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element)
{
    $innerHTML = "";
    $children = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}
```

Here are my var_dumps :
1/
    var_dump($dom);

```
object(DOMDocument)[1000]
  public 'doctype' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'implementation' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'documentElement' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'actualEncoding' => null
  public 'encoding' => null
  public 'xmlEncoding' => null
  public 'standalone' => boolean true
  public 'xmlStandalone' => boolean true
  public 'version' => null
  public 'xmlVersion' => null
  public 'strictErrorChecking' => boolean true
  public 'documentURI' => null
  public 'config' => null
  public 'formatOutput' => boolean true
  public 'validateOnParse' => boolean false
  public 'resolveExternals' => boolean false
  public 'preserveWhiteSpace' => boolean false
  public 'recover' => boolean false
  public 'substituteEntities' => boolean false
  public 'nodeName' => string '#document' (length=9)
  public 'nodeValue' => null
  public 'nodeType' => int 13
  public 'parentNode' => null
  public 'childNodes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'firstChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'lastChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'previousSibling' => null
  public 'attributes' => null
  public 'ownerDocument' => null
  public 'namespaceURI' => null
  public 'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'localName' => null
  public 'baseURI' => null
  public 'textContent' => string 'TEST1  TEST2. TEST3 TESTTTT' (length=32)
```

2/ Here it's OK because in my string I have 2 `<p>` tags and the `var_dump(pTags)` returns me `int2`

```
var_dump(pTags);
object(DOMNodeList)[1001]
     public 'length' => int 2
```

3/ Here we can see the 2 `<p>` tags with the `var_dump($pTag);`

```
var_dump($pTag);
object(DOMElement)[1040]
  public 'tagName' => string 'p' (length=1)
  public 'schemaTypeInfo' => null
  public 'nodeName' => string 'p' (length=1)
  public 'nodeValue' => string 'TEST1  TEST2. TEST3 ' (length=21)
  public 'nodeType' => int 1
  public 'parentNode' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'childNodes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'firstChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'lastChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'previousSibling' => null
  public 'nextSibling' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'attributes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'ownerDocument' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
  public 'namespaceURI' => null
  public 'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'localName' => string 'p' (length=1)
  public 'baseURI' => null
  public 'textContent' => string 'TEST1  TEST2. TEST3 ' (length=21)



object(DOMElement)[1062]
      public 'tagName' => string 'p' (length=1)
      public 'schemaTypeInfo' => null
      public 'nodeName' => string 'p' (length=1)
      public 'nodeValue' => string 'TESTTTT' (length=7)
      public 'nodeType' => int 1
      public 'parentNode' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'childNodes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'firstChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'lastChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'previousSibling' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'attributes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'ownerDocument' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'namespaceURI' => null
      public 'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'localName' => string 'p' (length=1)
      public 'baseURI' => null
      public 'textContent' => string 'TESTTTT' (length=7)
```

4/ Here, if the `<p>` tag have no `<show>` tag, I add `<show>` tag into the `<p>` tag . It works for my 2nd `<p>` tag where initialy there wasn't a `<show>` tag :

```
var_dump($valuePTagFull);
string '<show class='st'>TESTTTT</show>' (length=31)
```

5/ But I have a problem here. When I do the `var_dump($value_purified);` at the end of my code, he show me that :

```
string '<show class="st" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-moy="0.12125" data-time-start="0.28" id="1"><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="0.28">TEST1&nbsp; </word><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="1.25"> </word></show><show class="st" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-moy="0.13857142857143" data-time-start="0.28" id="11"><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="0.28">TEST2. </word><word class="word" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-start="1.25"> </word></show><show class="st" data-time-end="1.25" data-time-moy="0.194" data-time-start="0.28" id="12"><word class="word" data-time-end="1.444" data-time-start="0.28">TEST3 </word></show>

TESTTTT' (length=695)
```

Why at the end the word 'TESTTT' is not between `<show>` tags ?? whereas in the `var_dump($valuePTagFull);` the `<show>` tags are in ... ?

Comment: I don't see any PHP at your code ?

Comment: Please post some PHP code so we can see how these are built up. you might easily be able to do this in PHP

Comment: It's just a string that I get from a request form which have this shape <p><div></div></p><p><div></div></p>....

Comment: I would use the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) class and it's affiliated classes to accomplish your goal. You can then use a [XPath](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php) expression to find the corresponding p-Tags inside your Document and then check whether it has the required div-Tag as a child element or not. The `DOMDocument` API also allows you to add and modify elements of the DOM tree. You could then insert the div-Tags and output your HTML code with `DOMDocument::saveHTML()`

Comment: @ILadis Interesting ! I will see in this way !

Comment: @ILadis I edited my post, can u help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution manipulating the DOMDocument to get the desired results. See comments for details:

```
class foo
{
    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;

        // Load contents wrapped in a temporary root node
        $dom->loadXML('<root>' . $value . '</root>');

        // Use an XPath query to get all P elements
        $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $pTags = $xPath->query('//p');

        // Loop through the P elements
        $dataStart = 0;
        $dataEnd   = 0;

        foreach ($pTags as $pTag) {
            // Get any DIV elements inside the P
            $divs = $xPath->query('./div', $pTag);

            if ($divs->length > 0) {
                // This P element already has a div. Grab the
                // data-start/end attributes for later
                $div = $divs->item(0);
                $dataStart = $div->getAttribute('data-start');
                $dataEnd   = $div->getAttribute('data-end');
            }
            else {
                // Create a new DIV element and set attributes
                $div = $dom->createElement('div');
                $div->setAttribute('class',      'ST');
                $div->setAttribute('data-start', $dataStart);
                $div->setAttribute('data-end',   $dataEnd);

                // Move all children of P into DIV
                $child = $pTag->firstChild;
                while ($child) {
                    $nextChild = $child->nextSibling;
                    $div->insertBefore($child);
                    $child = $nextChild;
                }

                // Move the DIV inside the P element
                $pTag->appendChild($div);
            }
        }
        // Get HTML, removing temporary root element
        $html = preg_replace(
            '#.*?<root>\s*(.*)\s*</root>#s', '\1',
            $dom->saveXML()
        );
        return $html;
    }
}

$string = <<<EOS
<p>
    Blabla1 Blabla2
</p>
<p>
    <div data-start="1" data-end="5">
        <span>Blabla3 </span><span>Blabla4</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    Blabla5 Blabla6
</p>
<p>
    Blabla7 Blabla8
</p>
<p>
    <div data-start="6" data-end="10">
        <span>Blabla9 </span><span>Blabla10</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    Blabla11 Blabla12
</p>
EOS;

echo (new foo)->reverseTransform($string), PHP_EOL;
```

Output (indented for clarity):

```
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="0" data-end="0">
        Blabla1 Blabla2
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div data-start="1" data-end="5">
        <span>Blabla3 </span>
        <span>Blabla4</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
        Blabla5 Blabla6
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="1" data-end="5">
        Blabla7 Blabla8
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div data-start="6" data-end="10">
        <span>Blabla9 </span>
        <span>Blabla10</span>
    </div>
</p>
<p>
    <div class="ST" data-start="6" data-end="10">
        Blabla11 Blabla12
    </div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's a valid html, you can use the loadHTML function and manipulate your string way much faster: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php